# Python Requests working slow on my Laptop but working fast on my macbook

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler, screen-scraping

```
start = t.time()
response = requests.get(url='https://stackify.com/web-application-problems/')
end = t.time()
print(response.status_code)
print(end-start)
```

---

### Laptop Output:
200
42.25020903

MacBookAir Output
200
0.545675423

Can somebody explain where is the problem, I haven`t tried to use the logger yet.
Both machines are on the same network.

Comment: do a speedtest on both

Comment: The response text from that URL is >315Kb so it could be a network performance issue. For comparison, it takes <60ms on my machine

Comment: Throttling? Redirects? Using a VPN on laptop and not on macbook? It could be many things but I think it's got not much to do with python at this point and more with your network configuration.

Comment: Well I was able to figure out a solution from one of the other posts, unfortunately I missed the link, the workaround for this is that I needed to specify the timeout parameter in order to reduce the parsing times as by default the request parameter (on windows machine idk why) waits indefinitely for the page to load. I was able to do parallel and multiple requests in less than a second once the timeout value was passed.